# How do I restrict the types of tags and classes allowed?

Tags: editor, quill, richtextediting, prose

I would like to restrict the type of document created by a rich-text-editor. Let's assume color/styling is handled via CSS, and I only want the content editable document to be of the type:

```
<p class="r">I am red</p>
<p class="g">I am green</p>
<p class="b">I am blue</p>
<p class="b">I am <b>blue bold</b></p>
```

The rules are:
 * All content are in `<p>` tags.
 * Every `<p>` has to have a class assigned to it, which can be 'r', 'g' or 'b'.
 * The content inside the

tag can be only styled by `<b>` or `<i>`.
 * No nested `<p>` tags.

Is it possible to initialize a quilljs editor/ prose-editor/other to only allow documents of this types. Note that `<p>` and `<b>` are stand-ins.. it would be ok if the solution is to use `<div>` / `<strong>`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Clipboard](http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/) module in Quill is responsible for converting pasted content to the [Delta](http://quilljs.com/docs/delta/) format. The Clipboard supports adding [custom matchers](http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#addmatcher).

By default Quill whitelist all supported [formats](http://quilljs.com/docs/formats/)(Bold, Italic...). You can limit the formats with a [whitelist](http://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/#formats). You can also [extend](http://quilljs.com/guides/how-to-customize-quill/#content-and-formatting) existing formats and create new formats.

You can create a custom Class Attributor for the r, g, b classes and add it to the whitelist. You might be able to remove nested p tags with a Clipboard custom matcher or pre-process your content with regex.